# Find intersection of two lists by KeyAttribute and property value

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I want to get the intersection of two lists by reflection of the KeyAttribute properties values :

This given me the primary key properties (for composite) :

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> keys = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute)));
```

Now, how can I find the intersection of two lists ?

```
private static ICollection<T> Except<T>(this ICollection<T> source, ICollection<T> toIgnore)
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> keys = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute)));
    return source.Where(x => ???);
}
```

The final use case I want is : `var result = firstList.Except(second);`
It must return items of the first list who don't match key properties values with the second list.

EDIT :

I can do something like that but it works only when one property

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKey)
{
    return from item in items
            join otherItem in other on getKey(item) equals getKey(otherItem) into tempItems
            from temp in tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ReferenceEquals(null, temp) || temp.Equals(default(T))
            select item;
}

private static int GetPrimaryKey<T>(T item)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        KeyAttribute attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<KeyAttribute>();
        if (attr != null)
        {
            return int.Parse(property.GetValue(item).ToString());
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The `Func<T, TKey> getKey` takes the type T in and returns the type TKey. Type TKey can be of dynamic type. So your code could be something like the following -> `var result = list1.Except(list2, x => new { x.Field1, x.Field2 });`  That's what will be used for the join in the extension method you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual use-case you could consider building an expression tree to do some caching. Anyway here is a straight forward reflection solution (https://dotnetfiddle.net/zfK1SU):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var l1 = new List<ClassB>()
        {
            new ClassB() { KeyOne = 3, KeyTwo = 0 },
            new ClassB() { KeyOne = 5, KeyTwo = 0 },
            new ClassB() { KeyOne = 3, KeyTwo = 1 },
            new ClassB() { KeyOne = 5, KeyTwo = 1 }
        };

        var l2 = new List<ClassB>()
        {
            new ClassB() { KeyOne = 5, KeyTwo = 0 }
        };

        var x = Except(l1, l2).ToList();
        x.Dump();

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        var keyProps = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(KeyAttribute))).ToList();

        return items.Where(x => !other.Any(o => keyProps.All(prop => prop.GetValue(x).Equals(prop.GetValue(o)))));
    }
}


public class ClassB
{
    [Key]
    public int KeyOne { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int KeyTwo { get; set; }

    public string NoKey { get; set; }
}
```